# Alternatives to (Measure-Object -sum).Sum

Tags: powershell, csv, sum, measure-object

I'm stuck in the following situation:
I have to get information out of a CSV file. I imported the CSV using `Import-Csv`.

My raw data looks like this:

```
45227;01.10.2018 03:24:00;Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxx x XX xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;3;XXXX;XXXX;XXX@XX.com;;;3.7;;
```

where the column containing `3.7` is the value of interest ("Points").

Here comes my first problem --> Using `Import-Csv`, powershell will save this information in a `[string]` property. To avoid that i used the following line:

```
| Select @{Name="Points";Expression={[decimal]$_.Points}}
```

Now i'm getting a `Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`-typed object containing that property as a `[decimal]`. Now i wanted to sum up all the points, that were used by the same e-mail address:

```
$Data[$Index].Points += (
  $Imported_CSV | where {$_.Sender -eq $Imported_CSV_Unique.Sender} | 
    measure Points -sum
).Sum
```

This seemed to work just fine, but if i open up `$Data[$Index] | gm` i'm getting this: `Points           NoteProperty double Points=71301.6000000006`

The property changed to `[double]`. I dug a bit and i found out that Powershell's `GenericMeasureInfo.Sum` Property can only give back a `Nullable<Double>` instance as a property value.

It seems like i'm producing an overflow of `[double]`, because the number being displayed is totally wrong. I want to stick to decimal or integer so i have an output like `71123.4` or something like that.

Is there any other approach for that, so i don't have to use `(Measure-Object -sum).Sum` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. In the example CSV, show us the headers aswell. Where does `$Imported_CSV_Unique.Sender` in your code come from? Can't you simply do something like `[decimal]$sum = 0; $yourData | ForEach-Object { $sum += $_.Points}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

If you need to **control the *specific numeric data type*** used for ***summing up* numbers**:

- Avoid `Measure-Object`, which invariably uses `[double]` calculations.
- Instead, use the **LINQ [`Sum` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum)** (accessible in PSv3+) with a ***cast* to the desired numeric type**:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Sum(
  [decimal[]] @(
    $Imported_CSV | where {$_.Sender -eq $Imported_CSV_Unique.Sender}
  ).Points
)
```

---

[Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55207307/45375) helpful answer shows you an elegant way to sum your `Points` column grouped by rows that share the same email address and [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55208090/45375) improves on it by truly summing the points as `[decimal]` values.

Some **general points about [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) with `-Sum` and floating-point data types**:

You correctly state:

> The property [data type] changed to `double` [...] i found out that Powershell's `GenericMeasureInfo.Sum` property can only give back a `Nullable<Double>` as property value.

Indeed: `Measure-Object -Sum`:

- *invariably* uses `[double]` values to sum up the inputs.
- it *coerces* the inputs to `[double]`s, if possible - even if they're not numbers.

  - If an input cannot be coerced to a `[double]` (e.g., `'foo'`), an non-terminating error is emitted, but summing continues with any remaining inputs.

The above implies that **even *strings* are acceptable input to `Measure-Object -Sum`**, because they'll be converted to `[double]` on demand during summation.
That means that you could use your `Import-Csv` command *directly*, as in the following example (which uses two `[pscustomobject]` instances to simulate `Import-Csv`'s output):

```
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ Points = '3.7' }, [pscustomobject] @{ Points = '1.2' } |
      Measure-Object Points -Sum).Sum
4.9  # .Points property values were summed correctly.
```

> `71301.6000000006` [...] It seems like i'm producing an overflow of "double"

*Overflow* would imply exceeding the maximum value that can be stored in a `[double]`, which is (a) unlikely (`[double]::MaxValue` is `1.79769313486232E+308`, i.e., greater than 10 to the power of 308) and (b) would produce a different symptom; e.g.:

```
PS> ([double]::MaxValue, [double]::MaxValue | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
∞  # represents positive infinity
```

What you *do* get, however, is ***rounding*** errors due to the `[double]` type's internal *binary* representation, which doesn't always have an exact *decimal* representation, which can lead to baffling calculation results; e.g.:

```
PS> 1.3 - 1.1 -eq 0.2
False # !! With [double]s, 1.3 - 1.1 is NOT exactly equal to 0.2
```

<sup>For more information, see https://floating-point-gui.de/</sup>

**Using `[decimal]` values does solve this problem**, but note that this comes at the expense of a *smaller range* (in effect, you get 28 decimal digits of precision - the absolute value of the max. number depends on where the decimal point is placed; as an integer, it is `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335`, i.e. close to 8 * 10<sup>28</sup>).

**If you do need the precision of `[decimal]`s, you must avoid `Measure-Object` and do your own summing**.

In the context of your original command, you could use the `Sum` LINQ method:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Sum(
  [decimal[]] @(
    $Imported_CSV | where {$_.Sender -eq $Imported_CSV_Unique.Sender}
  ).Points
)
```

- The use of `@(...)` (the array subexpression operator) rather than just `(...)` around the pipeline command ensures that the overall command doesn't fail in case the pipeline happens to return *no rows*.  `@(...)` turns the non-output into an *empty array*, for which `.Sum()` correctly returns `0`.

  - Without it, the `[decimal[]]` cast would result in `$null`, and PowerShell wouldn't be able to find the `[decimal[]]`-typed overload of the `.Sum()` method and report an error, "Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Sum" and the argument count: 1".
- The above command invariably requires all matching CSV rows (represented as custom objects) into memory *as a whole*, whereas `Measure-Object` - as most cmdlets in the PowerShell pipeline - would process them *one by one*, which requires only a constant amount of memory (but is slower).

If loading all matching rows into memory at once is not an option, use the `ForEach-Object` (`foreach`) cmdlet, but note that this would only make sense if you substituted an actual `Import-Csv` call for the already-in-memory array `$Imported_Csv`:

```
# Replace $Imported_Csv with the original Import-Csv call to 
# get memory-friendly one-by-one processing.
$Imported_CSV | where {$_.Sender -eq $Imported_CSV_Unique.Sender} |
  foreach -Begin { [decimal] $sum = 0 } -Process { $sum += $_.Points } -End { $sum }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by grouping all the sender addresses together and then sum them individually:

```
Import-Csv .\data.csv |Group-Object Sender |ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Sender = $_.Name
        SumOfPoints = ($_.Group |Measure-Object Points -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

`Measure-Object` will automatically cast the `Points` strings to `[double]` - if you require more precision you can manually cast to `[decimal]` like before:

```
Import-Csv .\data.csv |Select-Object Sender,@{Name="Points";Expression={[decimal]$_.Points}} |Group-Object Sender |ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Sender = $_.Name
        SumOfPoints = ($_.Group |Measure-Object Points -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea to use `Group-Object` (+1); note, however, that in the second command you'll lose the `[decimal]` precision again when you call `Measure-Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Using grouping like [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) already did, here is how you can get the sum without losing the decimal precision, as I have commented before:

```
# faking the Import-Csv here with a here-string.
# in real life, you would use: Import-Csv <yourdata.csv> -Delimiter ';'
$data = @"
Sender;Date;Description;Something;Number;Whatever;DontKnow;Email;Nothing;Zilch;Points;Empty;Nada
45227;01.10.2018 03:24:00;Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxx x XX xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;3;XXXV;XXXA;XXX@XX.com;;;3.7;;
45227;01.10.2018 03:24:00;Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxx x XX xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;3;XXXW;XXXB;XXX@XX.com;;;4.7;;
45226;01.10.2018 03:24:00;Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxx x XX xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;3;XXXX;XXXC;XXX@XX.com;;;4.777779;;
45225;01.10.2018 03:24:00;Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxx x XX xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;3;XXXY;XXXD;XXX@XX.com;;;4.8;;
45225;01.10.2018 03:24:00;Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxx x XX xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;3;XXXZ;XXXE;XXX@XX.com;;;4.9;;
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

#get the two columns you need from the Csv and group them by Sender
$data | Select-Object Sender, Points | Group-Object Sender | ForEach-Object {
    # add the 'Points' values as decimal
    [decimal]$sum = 0
    foreach ($value in $_.Group.Points) { $sum += [decimal]$value }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Sender = $_.Name
        Sum    = $sum
    }
}
```

Output from the above would be:

> ```
> Sender      Sum
> ------      ---
> 45227       8,4
> 45226  4,777779
> 45225       9,7
> ```